# Outer Measures - Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory

In the definition of an outer measure, they state the sub-additivity condition as

$\mu_{*}(\bigcup A_{n}) \leq \sum\mu_{*}(A_{n})$ for any sequence of sets $A_{n} \subset X$

My question is does this inequality turn to an equality when the $A_{n}$ are disjoint sets and if it does then what would the difference be between an Outer measure and a measure?

Comment: No it does not automatically change to equality if the sets are disjoint. In some outer measures it may happen that it does but not in general.

Comment: Ok, so suppose we have a sequence of disjoint sets such that the inequality turns to an equality, then would those disjoint sets be considered as $\mu*$ measurable

Comment: Do you know what Caratheodorys measurability criterion is?

Comment: oh is it that a set A is $\mu_{*}$ measurable if for any set $E \subset X$ we have $\mu_{*}(E) = \mu_{*}(E \bigcap A) + \mu_{*}(E \bigcap A^{c} )$

Comment: Yes, so equality above does not really give us information about the particular $A_n$'s with which we can show measurability.

Comment: ok that makes sense now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the comments above, for an explicit counterexample to your first question (*does this inequality turn to an equality when the $A_n$ are disjoint sets...*), consider $\mu$ defined on $(\mathbb{N},2^{\mathbb{N}})$ (notation: $2^{\mathbb{N}} = $ power set of $\mathbb{N}$) by
\begin{equation}
\mu(A) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\quad A \neq \emptyset\\
0 & \text{if} \quad A = \emptyset,
\end{cases}
\quad\quad \text{where} \quad A \in 2^{\mathbb{N}}.
\end{equation}

It is easy to see that $\mu$ is an outer measure, but $\mathbb{N} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \{n\}$ is a disjoint union and

\begin{equation}
1 = \mu(\mathbb{N}) < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\mu(\{n\}) = + \infty
\end{equation}